# Red output is not getting output in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to print in colour, but it is not working. My code is below.

```
#######################Tool KIT #####################
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
print('a)kit1\nb)kit2')
env = raw_input('Please Choose the option:')
print(env)
if env == 'a':
print('You are choosen kit1 ')
elif env == 'b':
 print('You are choosen kit2')
else:
print (FAIL+ "Please Provide proper input \nExample: You should press a for      kit1 and b for kit2.\n Try again!")
```

Below is the output I am getting in Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

```
  Try again![93m
```

Also, please provide advice for choosing the option. Am I using the right way, or is there a better way?

Comment: It prints all red without errors on my mac.  Perhaps the \n is messing it up on windows.  Try \r\n

Comment: works fine on windows too.

Comment: Its not working for me :( are you guys testing in python 2.7?

Comment: Appears red in Python 2.7 on a Mac as well

Comment: Fix the broken indentation in your code. It's recommended to use 4 spaces to indent a code block.

Comment: As to getting color in a cross-platform way, try [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama). You can print in color with VT100 escapes in Windows 10. However, it's not enabled by default, so you may as well just use colorama since with it your code will also work in older versions of Windows.

Comment: @eryksun, yes i tried in linux and working and windows 10 i need to try using colorama